# using split on Array Object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, split

Why do I get mssg with "cannot find symbol", when I use .split on the String Object?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


String[] inputFile = StdIn.readAllLines().split("\\n");

//create Congress caracteristics
int states = Integer.parseInt(inputFile[0]);        // read states value and save in the first 
//position in the array

int totalSeats = Integer.parseInt(inputFile[1]);   //read number of seats and save in the second
//position in the array
```

Comment: `split` is a method of String not String[](the return type of readAllLines)..please read the docs.

Comment: Minor note: `StdIn` is a class created by Princeton for their Intro to Computer Science course: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are trying to call the split method on an array.  There is no such method on an array.  `readAllLines()` already returns an array of the strings.  Just remove the .split() call.

From the [JavaDoc](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html#readAllLines()):

> `static String[] readAllLines()`
>
> Reads all remaining lines from standard input and returns them as an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

`StdIn.readAllLines()` does not return a String but a `String[]` (array of strings). You can't use `split()` on an array of strings.

Actually, you don't need to do that, because calling `readAllLines()` already gives you the array you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely calling #split() in an Array/Collection of Strings, not a String. You should iterate though them and split one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
   We have fileName Object we itrate it a split it simple  in this program i split my object with (.) so thats why i used this =split("\\.");



    String[] fileName="we have a object here to we want to splite it ";


    for(String obj:FileName)
            {
        String[] part1=obj.split("\\.");
            }
    System.out.println(part1);



    check it its working fine
```